# vim block replace selection globally

Tags: vim

After I select something using v (eg. foo), I want to be able to replace all occurrences of foo in the entire file.  Is there a way to do that?  If I use

```
%s/\%V/bar/g
```

it is only limited to that instance of the word match.

Answer (score 4):

You can always yank the text and use it in the substitution command like this:

```
:%s/<C-R>"/new text/g
```

The `<C-R>"` stands for you pressing `Ctrl+r` and then selecting the `"` register (where yanked or deleted text goes by default). The only downside to this would be if the yanked text contained regex syntax.

This won't work with visual block selections.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just about a single word ("foo" in your example), you can place the cursor on it and use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> to insert the word under the cursor. No need for visual mode at all.

Or, to say it in Vim:

```
:%s/<C-R><C-W>/bar/g
```

Likewise, <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> inserts the everything until a whitespace character (useful for words-with-special-characters).

Also see `:help c_<C-R>_<C-W>`.